# Why is a gas less soluble in an aqueous solution of electrolytes than pure water?

Tags: solubility

Please help me out! This was given as a fact in my textbook but I don't understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2):

*Gist of the matter...*

When an ionic salt dissolves in water the ions and water molecules don't just bounce around independently. The ions have a charge and water molecules are polar. So the water molecules form a cluster, which is a number of concentric layers of  water molecules, around the ions. A gas molecule dissolved in the water can't get into a cluster. Hence there is effectively less water in which the gas can dissolve.